# How to create a folder under "/sys/class/thermal/"

Tags: linux-device-driver

Is it possible to develop a Linux device driver which creates a folder under "/sys/class/thermal" without ACPI or Device Tree changes ?

I could create a folder under the "/sys/kernel" or "/sys/firmware" like this.

```
   kobj_ref = kobject_create_and_add("my_device", kernel_kobj);     // /sys/kernel
   kobj_ref = kobject_create_and_add("my_device", firmware_kobj);       // /sys/firmware
```

But I couldn't find an object, representing the "/sys/class/thermal", or an API to convert the file path to kobject.

Thank you

Comment: Why exactly would you want to do that? Unless whatever you are trying concerns itself with the thermal framework in which case it would be under drivers/thermal. What you want is basically done by the device_register functions provided by thermal_core and thermal_hwmon. If you want to create a driver in thermal class, you should go via thermal core and not call kobject_create_and_add manually.

Comment: I was trying to develop a pseudo thermal driver in quick-and-dirty way,  to test a thermal control application. I was hoping to achieve this without learning the thermal zone driver framework. As I couldn’t find an easy way, I spend a few days to create my driver in the framework, as you suggested. Thank you for the input.

Comment: Did you get to know how to do it? Or you went the framework way?